# Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters, its in mongodb and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHi8J.png)I am trying to do a get request for each blog when they are clicked but for some reason its not working am getting an error. Here is my code.

```
<% blogs.forEach(blog => { %>
  <a href="/blogs/ <%= blog._id %> ">
  <h3> <%= blog.title %>  </h3>
  <p> <%= blog.snippet %>  </p>
  </a>
<% }) %>

<div class="details content">
   <h2> <%= blog.title %>  </h2>
<div class="content">
   p> <%= blog.body %>  </p>
</div>
</div>

app.get('/blogs/:id', (req,res) => {
const id = req.params.id;
Blog.findById(id)
.then(result => {
res.render("details", {blog: result});
})
.catch(err => {
console.log("Error", err);
})
})
```

Comment: Show me the result of console.log(req.params.id)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHi8J.png   this is it

Comment: are you using bodyparser?

Comment: am not using it but i have just copy pasted what you have given me and installed body parser but it is still not working

Comment: do you use postman for sending request?

Comment: no i dont use it

Comment: check the header of request, because in header of request should be   `headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }`

Comment: your code is correctly, the http request is incorrect

Comment: am on it thank you

Answer (score 0):

just try like this

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
```